# R analysis of a GIS-created network

Tags: r, networking, spatial, arcgis, degrees

I have a bunch of Networks drawn in ArcGIS on a basemap. Now I have to check their connectedness and determine their degree distributions. No ArcGIS functions (e.g., Collect Event) have worked so far, and the number of nodes&edges is too high to perform a case-by-case check.

**How could this task be done in R?**

*I have an .xls file with both nodes coordinates (North and East) and edges coordinates (North and East for start, North and East for end). Workflow must be: 1) check connectedness; 2) degree distribution. Networks are of mixed nature (both directed and undirected), but at first I would like to consider them as being all undirected. Later, I will consider their true nature.*

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Trivial in R. Read the spreadsheet, use the igraph package to make a network graph, then connectedness and degree distribution are about two functions away. But how much R do you know? Where are we starting from? Although igraph doesn't care about the coordinates, only the ID of node connections... Do you have that? What does that spreadsheet look like?

Comment: Good to know it's trivial. I am an R beginner. We are starting from an xls file which stores the coordinates for both the Nodes and the Edges. What do you exactly mean by "the ID of node connections"? All I have are the node IDs and the edge IDs. I wanted to check the connectedness by confronting the X+Y coordinates of each node with the X+Y_start and X+Y_end coordinates of the edges. Do you think this will be done more easily with something else? e.g., Java or Phyton? Thanks.

Comment: The spreadsheet looks like this: **Nodes** -> OBJECTID | X Coord | Y Coord | X+Y; **Edges** -> OBJECTID | X_start | Y_start | X_end | Y_end | X+Y_start | X+Y_end; such data come from ArcGIS 10.2.

Comment: Of course, if an edge is properly connected to a node, either its X,Y_start or X+Y_end must coincide with the X+Y of the node. Ideally, once I have a report table, I will get back to ArcGIS to adjust the connectedness. Does it make sense?

Comment: Your spreadsheet structure doesn't *explicitly* tell you the connections, it seems. You have to work them out from the coordinates. This is called "building the topology" and should be something you can do in a GIS. Then to do any analysis in R, the output would be something like a list of pairs of OBJECTID1, OBJECTID2 values, each showing a connection between node OBJECTID1 and OBJECTID2 - no coordinates needed. I'm surprised if ArcGIS can't do this...

Comment: Yes, my spreadsheet does not tell me anything about connectivity, and this is a problem. It is just as well that you are surprised - there is no way of obtaining the list of pairs you mention from ArcGIS. You can only do it programmatically, but it is not in my interest now to do this with ArcGIS.

Comment: Okay, I really think now you need to give us a sample excel file so we're all working from the same point.

Comment: Excel file: **http://www.filedropper.com/verticesstack**. **Recap**:1) I have a network made of nodes (manholes) and edges (pipes) drawn on GIS; 2) Links verified as vertices correspond to pipe starting and ending points; 3) GIS cannot deliver the Adjacency Matrix -> rows: node ID; columns: node ID; values: 0 or 1 (0=nodes not connected; 1=nodes connected); 4) **I need such matrix to work out the degree distribution, & need a table with relations like "Node 125 -> Node 17"**; 5) Excel file: please refer to **Vertices_Sewer** (for edges) & **Vertices_Manholes** (for nodes). Thank you very much.

Comment: There are duplicate coordinates for some of the manholes. What to do with those?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is a mistake I have just discovered and worked out. Unbeknownst to me there were multiple points piled on top of each other at some locations. I will now provide you with the correct file. This will only change data in the Vertices_Manholes tab. The rest will remain unchanged. I apologize.

Comment: Here you can find the correct file: http://www.filedropper.com/verticesstackcorrect - Thank you for your dedication!